# How to simulate icing on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Just like many screen saver apps that simulate water wave,  I want to simulate the process of icing, from water to ice, what tech do I need to learn? Is there any example code?

Comment: And here's me thinking someone wants to put delicious cake frosting onto a phone...

Comment: iPhone and yummy frosting is two of my favorite things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,  you should go for the Open GL, which is the most preferred way of such type of effects, even though it is not that much simple (as it sounds :) )

These might be helpful you :

[the-water-effect-explained](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/special-effects/water/the-water-effect-explained-r915)

[Water Effects](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=11)

[how-to-generate-water-in-opengl](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/312821-how-to-generate-water-in-opengl/)

Answer (score 4):

It's not a trivial problem.  This paper might be a good starting point:

**Visual Simulation of Ice Crystal Growth**

 https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:Yb2KyCqKDB0J:citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi%3D10.1.1.5.1550%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf+&hl=lv&gl=lv&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESi4BkAj7ppAttOV-BnYLiu8YYO7lRZiq7U_iMHW5T4DG1BNcVdEvGHeSj6CJBEMgdilOuRd3woHbkH4wWUKLfR8_o6sGu3mmGMYtak6qY9LcEcqthZTQnv9W7wz6H_vqQTOVE0X&sig=AHIEtbRBNTYhCw7UxHCcu8SjRAJg93oNzw&pli=1